# Numerous modal windows on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

What is the best way to show for example 50 different modals on a single page. I'm developing a page that has a lot of modal windows opening up. Also modal window opens up another modal window.

What is the best way technically to show these modal window on a single page. I don't think I should add 50 modal HTML code every time the page loads and there is no need to call all 50 beforehand when the page loads, because the page HTML will get huge.

I think there should be a better way to handle this scenario. I noticed on some sites that show a lot of modal windows, where the modal div seems to disappear from the DOM when the modal is closed, but I don't know how they are doing it. It certainly didn't seem like they added all the 50 modal HTML DOMs to the page DOM on initial page load.

Has anyone has done anything like this scenario where a page might have gigantic modals. Is there HTML JS injection going on where there are HTML modal templates stored somewhere and when on button click scenario, the specific modal HTML is injected/swapped into the DOM using JQuery and when on modal close click the modal div is removed from the DOM or something?

Any help, answer, comment is appreciated.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do not have 50 modals on one page - nor that you open one modal from another one - what you want to do is to have one modal and then swap the content of of that modal as required. For example- setting the modal title, modal body, action buttons in the modal footer etc. Whilst you have more than one modal open at the same time - it is a really bad UX (IMO) and can lead to confusion about the flow and current state. Far better to modify the content in the one modal.

Comment: How would the content swapping work? I'm kinda confused on that part. Is it through JQuery template append/injection? How is it done technically?

Comment: No need to create `n` modal, just  `one`  enough, you only should change the content. *That's All!*

Comment: How to change the content? Through 50 modal templates and injection/append? I know I need a single modal HTML and I need to swap, but how that can be done?

Comment: $('#myModal .modal-body').html(newContent)

Comment: For example make it `empty()` on click then, `$('.modal-body').html('// SET YOUR DESIRE HTML');`

Comment: Where should I store "newContent"? Should there be a template page or JS file where all the modal contents are stored? Please point me somewhere where I can see an example. I know I need single modal and html(_newContent)

Comment: It depend your logic and *what are you trying to do* , yes you can store new content in a `variable` OR  `localstorage`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show me an example? I just want to do this technically correct.

Comment: You need to explain what is these `50` modal content? for example you have 50 button that you want to show modal on click?

Comment: It is like a whole application, where each modal has multiple "<input>"s and each button has "save" and "close." It is like add/edit/delete modal windows. Modals are opened using <a href links. It is an AJAX page with where modal saves are done using AJAX. I'm new to modals.

Comment: i think best would be using ajax along with a single modal window, whatever you are opening the modal window for like say if you have product listing on a page render those products along with a common `class` and then bind an ajax call on click of these products the ajax call will fetch the content to be displayed inside the modal, and once complete you can add the content to the modal body and trigger the `$('#modal-name').modal('show')` to display data

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. Is this how it should be done where content is fetched using AJAX from the server? Is this the correct way to do it? I'm new to this many gigantic modals showing up on a single page. How should I store the modal HTML templates on the server? Should there be separate html files?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `function` to call `modal` like this:

```
function callModal(title, text){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
   $('.modal-title').text(title);
   $('.modal-body').text(text);
}
```

And insert content when function called. You can call function whenever you want, just pass content like title or text. something like this:

```
$('#Link1').click(function(){
   callModal('some title 1111', 'some text 1111');
});

$('#Link2').click(function(){
   callModal('some title 2222', 'some text 2222');
});
```

**[Online Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5pkz5x8o/)**

**Update:** For pass big `html` do this:

```
var myHtml = "<form>"
+"<div class='form-group'><h1>My Form</h1><input type='text' class='form-control'/></div>"
+"<div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control'/></div>"
+"<div class='form-group'><textarea class='form-control'></textarea></div>"
+"<input class='btn btn-success' value='submit'/>"
+"</form>";
```

**[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/5pkz5x8o/1/)**

Comment: Thank you. If my HTML is very large like 5-7 input fields, where should I store it? Should there be a separate file? If it is like ''some text 2222' this short it is fine.

Comment: As i said just store it in a `variable` , See updated answer